# Mongodb Get results from two tables

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collection:

songs:

```js
{    
  "song":"a",
  "singer":"singer 1",
  "album":"album 1",
}
{    
  "song":"b",
  "singer":"singer 1",
  "album":"album 1",
}
```

albums:

```js
{    
  "singer":"singer 1",
  "album":"album 1",
  "image":"ffffffff",
}
```

I want to search songs collection with (singer , album) And merge the album image with the results

Currently we are using the following code :

```js
  const list = await db
    .collection("songs")
    .find({
      albumSlug: params.album,
      singerSlug: params.singer,
    })
    .toArray();
```

The expected results are something like :

```js
songs:
{    
 "song":"a",
 "singer":"singer 1",
 "album":"album 1",
}
{    
  "song":"b",
  "singer":"singer 1",
  "album":"album 1",
}
image:
{
  "image":"ffffffff",
}
```

I use Next.js

Comment: You need to use aggregation with $lookup ( equivalent to SQL JOIN )  but for a document model it looks best if you embed the songs in an albums document...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and interest
Please give me an example of that because I have been using Mango DB from a short time